# subject field encoding in grails mail

Tags: email, grails, encoding

When using the Grails mail plugin, German special charachters lik ü or ä show up in the subject field as unreadable characters.
When I look at the mail raw data, it contains a utf-8 encoding. What I would need is a iso-8859-1 encoding.
Is there any way to do this using the mail plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is: no, tha mail plugin does not help you with that, it's not its responsibility. The correct  encoding of non ASCII characters in email subject is a little bit more complicated. Look at the related RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047, where the encoding is described.

there is an existing class from javax.mail package, which does the work for you:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html

Comment: Could you perhaps expand a bit on _why_ that isn't the responsibility of the Mail plugin?

Comment: @cdeszaq because it follows the :single responsibility principle". The mail plugin is responsible only for sending an email based on given input. To prepare the input correctly must be done via another responsible entity.

Comment: That's the point I was after => `To prepare the input correctly must be done via another responsible entity`